# Consider a continuous random variable X. Find some value c such that $ P(X>c) < 0.01 $.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

A coffee shop on campus receives its supplies of coffee grains once a week on Monday mornings. The amount of coffee grain (in kilograms) used in a week is a random variable with density function

$$ f(x) = \frac{3}{250}(1-\frac{x}{250})^2 \:\:\: if \:\:\: 0 <x<250 \:\:\: \text{and 0 otherwise.} $$

How much coffee should the shop buy on Monday so that the probability of running out of coffee that week is less than $0.01$?

I've attempted the question and will show how I've gone about it. Let:

$\text{X = coffee grain used in a week}$

$\text{c = amount of coffee the shop should buy in a week}$

Then what I think we should be looking for is a value for **c** such that

$$ P(X > c) < 0.01 \rightarrow 1 - P(X \leq c) < 0.01 \rightarrow P(X \leq c) \geq 0.99 \rightarrow F_X(c) \geq 0.99 $$

To find $F_X(c)$ we would integrate the pdf over the range (0, **c**) as follows:

$$ F_X(c) = \frac{3}{250} \int_0^c 1 - \frac{2x}{250} + \frac{x^2}{250^2} dx = \left.\frac{3x}{250} - \frac{3x^2}{250^2} + \frac{x^3}{250^3}\right|_0^c= \frac{3c}{250} - \frac{3c^2}{250^2} + \frac{c^3}{250^3} $$

And so we want to find the values of **c** that satisfy this inequality:

$$  \frac{3c}{250} - \frac{3c^2}{250^2} + \frac{c^3}{250^3} \geq 0.99 $$

This is where I seem to get stuck. I don't know how to solve for this inequality, I've tried to factor the polynomial but had no success with it. I suppose I'm out of my depth trying to solve it analytically.

So I resorted to solving it numerically. I threw together a simple script that solves the solution for all values ranging from (0, 250), incrementing by 0.00001 each loop. The smallest value that satisfies the inequality I found with this method was c = 196.13914. So my answer to this would be $ c \geq 196.13914 $.

However, it still feels like I'm missing something here. Is there an easier or more intuitive way to solve this question?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Do not expand the integrand. An antiderivative of $(1-x/250)^2$ is $-250(1-x/250)^3/3$. Much easier to work with...

Answer (score 1):

I followed at [@David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18986/david-mitra)'s advice by not expanding the integrand when taking the anti-derivative. After some mistakes with not updating the bounds I think I got the answer.

$$  F_X(c) = \frac{3}{250} \int_0^c (1 - \frac{x}{250})^2dx $$

$let \:\:\: u=1-\frac{x}{250} \:\:\: then \:\:\: du = -\frac{1}{250}dx \:\:\: and \:\:\: dx = -250du \:\:\: \text{re-writing our integral we get}$

$$ F_X(c) = \frac{3}{250} \int_1^{1-\frac{c}{250}} -250u^2du = \frac{3}{250} \left[\left. \frac{-250}{3}u^3 \right|_1^{1-\frac{c}{250}}\right] = \frac{3}{250} \left[ \frac{-250}{3}(1-\frac{c}{250})^3 - \frac{-250}{3} \right] = -(1-\frac{c}{250})^3 + 1 $$

So the inequality shown in the question above can be re-written as: $ -(1-\frac{c}{250})^3 + 1 \geq 0.99 $.

Which can be re-arranged to get:

$$ c \geq 250(\sqrt[3]{0.99-1} + 1) \\$$

Which when solved for c gives an answer similar to what I got numerically.

$ c \approx 196.13913 $